# Spring-Data-Jpa find all by relationship entity by specific value

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class ReportDistributionLog which as Many to One relationship defined as follows:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "report_distribution_id", referencedColumnName = "report_distribution_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public ReportDistribution getReportDistribution() {
    return reportDistribution;
}

public void setReportDistribution(ReportDistribution reportDistribution) {
    this.reportDistribution = reportDistribution;
}
```

i want to get all report distribution logs for which internal=true on report distribution level.

wrote this query:
    List findAllByReportDistributionInternal(boolean internal);

the list is always empty.

Comment: Pretty sure Spring-Data-Jpa doesn't support joins through interface method names.

Answer (score 1):

hello Victoria Serkov:

I 've used hql frequently when I had to get data with conditions.

In this case I suppose it must be something like:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from ReportDistributionLog where internal=true");
List list = query.list();
```

I hope this can help you. 
Let me know.
regards.